# How can i configure Workerman works through wss with nginx?

Tags: php, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, phpwebsocket

I just started to learn websockets with "Workerman" library on my nginx server, and i ran into a problem.

I tried some examples, so I think I almost made it. I have the following:

Script into **example.com/test/websockets.html**

```
   `...
<script> const ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com:4242"); ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log("Message from server!" + event.data);
    });
</script>
...`
```

PHP with Workerman in **example.com/test/websockets.php**

```
<?php

use Workerman\Worker;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create a Websocket server
$ws_worker = new Worker('websocket://example.com:4242');
$ws_worker->count = 4;

$ws_worker->onConnect = function ($connection) {
    //$connection->send('message');
    echo "New connection\n";
};

// Emitted when data received
$ws_worker->onMessage = function ($connection, $data) use ($ws_worker) {
    // Send hello $data
    $connection->send('Hello ' . $data);

    // For each client do this
    foreach($ws_worker->connections as $clientConnection){
        $clientConnection->send($data);
    }
};

// Emitted when connection closed
$ws_worker->onClose = function ($connection) {
    echo "Connection closed\n";
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

When i run PHP script, and go to exmaple.com/test/websockets.php i get next error in console:
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:4242/' failed:  (anonym) @ (index):9`
**But in script, i see, that i connected and disconnected immediately twice.**

So, i found that my server isn't set up to reverse proxy. I also can provide ssl certificates with my script - but i don't want to do it... I tried change my nginx configuration with next lines:

```
server {         
    
listen 443 http2 ssl;         
listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;               

location ~ ^/test/(.*$) {                 
tcp_nodelay on;                 
keepalive_timeout  1200s 1200s;                 
keepalive_requests 100000;                 
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4242/$1;                 
proxy_read_timeout 1200s;                 
proxy_send_timeout 1200s;                 
proxy_http_version 1.1;                 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                 
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";                 
proxy_set_header Host $host;                 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;        
}
```

This is wouldn't work for me.

**What else do I need to do and configure so that I can run websockets on my server? If possible, with examples**
**Please, if additional information is required, I will provide it. But I want to figure it out and get help**